# How can I connect to ubuntu at azure?

Tags: azure

I just created a ubuntu vm at microsoft azure.
But while it is running, the connect button is disable.
(Sorry, I am new at Stackoverflow, I don't know how to upload the error screenshot. I just can say the connect button is disable)
How can I connect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you created the Ubuntu VM, you should configuration first and you want to remote connect it.

***SSH***

You’ll need an SSH client to connect to your Ubuntu VM. Some options for Windows are:

- Cygwin (my preference, way more than just SSH and command-line based)
- Putty (a very popular option)

Now, connect to the server’s full DNS name “[servername].cloudapp.net” with ssh and login with the username you specified during setup.
Bug workaround – IMPORTANT! There seems to be some sort of problem with either Ubuntu, or Azure’s integration with it. The problem manifests after some software updates on the machine (most likely one in particular, but I’m not sure which one). The end result is that you lose your right to run “sudo,” thus removing all ability to access the machine as an administrator.

The only way I know that gets around this is to set a password for “root” (DO THIS NOW):

```
$ sudo passwd root
```

This will allow you to set up a password for the true “superuser” on the box, which is not enabled by default. Thus, when problems running sudo occur, you can login as the “root” user and continue. The good news is that the problem goes away after a reboot if you also run:

```
$ sudo usermod –G admin [username]
```

This puts your username in the “admin” group in order to make sure you continue to have sudo access after restarting. You will still have problems after the first update.

If, at any time, the system tells you that “username is not in the list of ‘sudoers,’” just use “su –“ and enter the root user’s password to proceed. This will not be necessary after a reboot.

Hopefully this will be fixed by the time you read this so you don’t experience this problem.

***Installing Desktop and Remote Support (xrdp)***

***The Desktop***

To use a Remote Desktop, we actually need to have a Desktop. So, we’ll install the standard Ubuntu Desktop followed by “xrdp”, which implements the RDP protocol with VNC server software as its backing. This is quite simple to do (just answer yes to any prompts):

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop 
$ sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

That’s it!

***Accessing the Desktop Remotely***

The simplest approach for allowing RDP access is to add an Endpoint to your Virtual Machine from the Portal. To do this, first click “Endpoints” at the top, then “Add Endpoint” on the bottom. Once there, add the Endpoint named “RDP” using TCP protocol and port 3389 (both public and private)

Once that’s done updating, you can go back to the VM screen and click “Connect” on the bottom of your screen:

This will download a “.rdp” file which will connect you to your VM.

You will be presented with a slightly unusual-looking login screen like this:

Note that you’ll need to change the “username” to your user and enter your password. Once that’s done, you’ll get an Ubuntu Desktop!

I’m sure you’ll notice that it’s not very fast. I highly recommend you use the Remote Desktop client’s Display options to select lower color depth (16-bit or lower) and as small a resolution as you feel comfortable with. This will speed things up considerably.

**More detailed information please see this link:
http://blog.appliedis.com/2012/11/05/remote-desktop-to-ubuntu-in-windows-azure/**

Comment: I followed the “Install Gnome Desktop” from (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/classic/remote-desktop). When I try to connect from Windows machine using Remote Desktop I get following error:

Couldn't connect.

Your session ended because there was a protocol error. If this keeps happening, ask your admin or tech support for help.

Any idea what is the cause of this issue?